# When pasting or importing SQL Server 2012 results into Excel 2007. The SQL Server results show 2600 rows, but excel shows over 5000

Tags: sql, excel, import, sql-server-2012, paste

We are seeing an issue when importing SQL Server 2012 results into Excel 2007. The SQL Server results show 2600 rows, but Excel shows over 5000. We are pretty sure the query isn't the issue since it works fine on two other machines.

One machine is running Vista, both the other machines including the problem box is running windows 7. The problem box is running SQL Server 2012, and the other two machines are running SQL Server 2005. All three are using Excel 2007.

We have a report to deliver in the morning but can't run the results on third box. Any idea what might cause this issue?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean microsoft SQL?

Comment: Is the problem machine showing exactly double the number of results that the other machines show? The figures given (over 5000 vs 2600) could suggest that

Comment: How are you importing the results?  You've tagged your question with "paste" but you could be a little more explicit around exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Please provide more detail. Have you closely examined the 2600 rows and the 5000 rows to see how they differ? How about some sample data? Could your Excel import process (you didn't say how you're importing) be treating CR LF as two individual line-end markers?